# 301 directory redirect exclude subdirectory

Tags: 301-redirect, subdirectory

I need to do a 301 directory redirect in my *httpd.conf* file but exclude a subdirectory within the directory.

Example: `RedirectPermanent /redirect/  http://www.mysite.com/`.

But I want to exclude this subdirectory `/redirect/example/`.

Any ideas?

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect/example/?$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/redirect/? mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please post it in your question.

Comment: I do not think you can do such exclusion with `RedirectPermenent` directive -- you need to use more powerful **`mod_rewrite`** where you can create much more powerful rules (compared to simple rules available for `RedirectPermanent`).

Comment: I tried this --- didnt work.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect/example/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/redirect/? http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]

Comment: 1) Have you restarted Apache after such changes? It is required to re-read `httpd.conf` file -- any changes there are not get picked up automatically (compared to .htaccess) 2) just FYI: this will redirect all in `redirect` folder except `/redirect/example` (I mean, `/redirect.example/1.html` will not be redirected) 3) Since you have access to `httpd.conf`, you can enable rewrite logging (on max level) and see why that particular request is failing

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a RedirectPermanent for the parent directory then setup a sym link to the example directory in your web root dir.

Now test that this much actually works. If it does, create an Alias (http.conf) for the old directory to now point to the new directory link.

Assuming that RedirectPermanent is just looking for URLs which begin with specific text this should work. Unfortunately, I haven't tested any of this but presume that it'd work.

Comment: After working on this off and on for a couple of days, I finally came up with a combination that works:

Comment: RewriteEngine on                                                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect/example/.*? [NC]           
RewriteRule ^/redirect/? http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]